# envoy proxy initialization take more than 3 minutes

Tags: envoyproxy

I'm using Envoy proxy to route the call with multiple clusters running on linux docker container. What I'm observing here initialization process takes more than 3 minutes and this is generally happening when the cluster's endpoint socket address is wrong (it's a case where the socket address is tokenized and it's not resolve during initialization of envoy proxy server).
Any suggestion how to resolve this delay?

```
[2021-05-07 13:16:39.125][7][info][config] [source/server/configuration_impl.cc:103] loading tracing configuration
[2021-05-07 13:16:39.125][7][info][config] [source/server/configuration_impl.cc:69] loading 0 static secret(s)
[2021-05-07 13:16:39.125][7][info][config] [source/server/configuration_impl.cc:75] loading 13 cluster(s)
[2021-05-07 13:16:39.137][7][info][config] [source/server/configuration_impl.cc:79] loading 6 listener(s)
[2021-05-07 13:16:39.150][7][info][config] [source/server/configuration_impl.cc:129] loading stats sink configuration
[2021-05-07 13:16:39.151][7][info][main] [source/server/server.cc:652] starting main dispatch loop
[2021-05-07 13:19:09.152][7][info][runtime] [source/common/runtime/runtime_impl.cc:524] RTDS has finished initialization
[2021-05-07 13:19:09.152][7][info][upstream] [source/common/upstream/cluster_manager_impl.cc:182] cm init: all clusters initialized
[2021-05-07 13:19:09.152][7][info][main] [source/server/server.cc:631] all clusters initialized. initializing init manager
[2021-05-07 13:19:09.152][7][info][config] [source/server/listener_manager_impl.cc:844] all dependencies initialized. starting workers
[2021-05-07 13:19:09.153][7][warning][main] [source/server/server.cc:537] there is no configured limit to the number of allowed active connections. Set a limit via the runtime key overload.global_downstream_max_connections
```

Also, I was reading about this initial_fetch_timeout (https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.12.0/api-v2/api/v2/core/config_source.proto#envoy-api-field-core-configsource-initial-fetch-timeout) but got not much clue on implementation of this.

below is the yaml I'm using:

```yaml
         admin:
      access_log_path: /var/log/envoy_admin_access.log
      address:
        socket_address:
          protocol: TCP
          address: 0.0.0.0
          port_value: 9901
    static_resources:
      listeners:
      - name: listener_http
        address:
          socket_address:
            protocol: TCP
            address: 0.0.0.0
            port_value: 8080
        filter_chains:
          filters:
          - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
            typed_config:
              "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
              stat_prefix: ingress_http
              access_log:
              - name: envoy.access_loggers.file
                typed_config:
                  "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.access_loggers.file.v3.FileAccessLog
                  path: /dev/stdout
              - name: envoy.access_loggers.file
                typed_config:
                  "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.access_loggers.file.v3.FileAccessLog
                  path: /var/log/envoy_httpaccessLog.log
              route_config:
                name: local_route
                virtual_hosts:
                - name: local_service
                  domains: 
                  - "*"
                  routes:
                  - match:
                      prefix: "/"
                    redirect: { https_redirect: true }
              http_filters:
              - name: envoy.filters.http.router
      - name: listener_https
        address:
          socket_address:
            protocol: TCP
            address: 0.0.0.0
            port_value: 8443
        filter_chains:
          transport_socket:
            name: envoy.transport_sockets.tls
            typed_config:
              "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.transport_sockets.tls.v3.DownstreamTlsContext
              common_tls_context:
                tls_certificates:
                - certificate_chain:
                    filename: "/etc/envoy/certificates/envoy.crt"
                  private_key:
                    filename: "/etc/envoy/certificates/envoy.key"
          filters:
          - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
            typed_config:
              "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
              stat_prefix: ingress_https
              access_log:
              - name: envoy.access_loggers.file
                typed_config:
                  "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.access_loggers.file.v3.FileAccessLog
                  path: /var/log/envoy_httpsAccessLog.log
              - name: envoy.access_loggers.file
                typed_config:
                  "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.access_loggers.file.v3.FileAccessLog
                  path: /dev/stdout
              route_config:
                name: local_route
                virtual_hosts:
                - name: local_service
                  domains: 
                  - "*"
                  routes:
                  - match:
                      prefix: "/.well-known"
                    route:
                      cluster: AuthServer
                  - match:
                      prefix: "/authserver"
                    route:
                      cluster: AuthServer
                  - match:
                      prefix: "/dl"
                    route:
                      cluster: dlServer
                  - match:
                      prefix: "/api/smart"
                    route:
                      cluster: SmartService
                  - match:
                      prefix: "/MetaData"
                    route:
                      cluster: MetaDataServer
                  - match:
                      prefix: "/MetaInfo"
                    route:
                      cluster: MetaDataServer
              http_filters:
              - name: envoy.filters.http.router 
      - name: listner_grpc
        address:
          socket_address:
            protocol: TCP
            address: 0.0.0.0
            port_value: 8090
        filter_chains:
          transport_socket:
            name: envoy.transport_sockets.tls
            typed_config:
              "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.transport_sockets.tls.v3.DownstreamTlsContext
              common_tls_context:
                alpn_protocols: "h2"
                tls_certificates:
                - certificate_chain:
                    filename: "/etc/envoy/certificates/envoy.crt"
                  private_key:
                    filename: "/etc/envoy/certificates/envoy.key"
          filters:
          - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
            typed_config:
              "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
              stat_prefix: ingress_http
              codec_type: auto
              access_log:
              - name: envoy.access_loggers.file
                typed_config:
                  "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.access_loggers.file.v3.FileAccessLog
                  path: /dev/stdout
              - name: envoy.access_loggers.file
                typed_config:
                  "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.access_loggers.file.v3.FileAccessLog
                  path: /var/log/envoy_tcpaccessLog.log
              route_config:
                name: local_grpc
                virtual_hosts:
                - name: local_service
                  domains: 
                  - "*"
                  routes:
                  - match:
                      prefix: "/"
                      grpc: {}
                    route:
                      cluster: gRPCServer
              http_filters:
              - name: envoy.filters.http.router
                typed_config: {}
      - name: listner_progress_grpc
        address:
          socket_address:
            protocol: TCP
            address: 0.0.0.0
            port_value: 8091
        filter_chains:
          transport_socket:
            name: envoy.transport_sockets.tls
            typed_config:
              "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.transport_sockets.tls.v3.DownstreamTlsContext
              common_tls_context:
                alpn_protocols: "h2"
                tls_certificates:
                - certificate_chain:
                    filename: "/etc/envoy/certificates/envoy.crt"
                  private_key:
                    filename: "/etc/envoy/certificates/envoy.key"
          filters:
          - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
            typed_config:
              "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
              stat_prefix: ingress_http
              codec_type: auto
              access_log:
              - name: envoy.access_loggers.file
                typed_config:
                  "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.access_loggers.file.v3.FileAccessLog
                  path: /dev/stdout
              - name: envoy.access_loggers.file
                typed_config:
                  "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.access_loggers.file.v3.FileAccessLog
                  path: /var/log/envoy_tcpaccessLog.log
              route_config:
                name: local_grpc
                virtual_hosts:
                - name: local_service
                  domains: 
                  - "*"
                  routes:
                  - match:
                      prefix: "/"
                      grpc: {}
                    route:
                      cluster: gRPCProgressServer
                      timeout: 0s
              http_filters:
              - name: envoy.filters.http.router
                typed_config: {} 
      - name: listener_tcp
        address:
          socket_address:
            protocol: TCP
            address: 0.0.0.0
            port_value: 32914
        filter_chains:
          filters:
          - name: envoy.filters.network.tcp_proxy
            typed_config:
              "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.tcp_proxy.v3.TcpProxy        
              stat_prefix: ingress_tcp
              cluster: gateway_cluster
              access_log:
              - name: envoy.access_loggers.file
                typed_config:
                  "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.access_loggers.file.v3.FileAccessLog
                  path: /dev/stdout
              - name: envoy.access_loggers.file
                typed_config:
                  "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.access_loggers.file.v3.FileAccessLog
                  path: /var/log/envoy_tcpaccessLog.log 
      - name: listener_teamviewer_tcp
        address:
          socket_address:
            protocol: TCP
            address: 0.0.0.0
            port_value: 11080
        filter_chains:
          filters:
          - name: envoy.filters.network.tcp_proxy
            typed_config:
              "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.tcp_proxy.v3.TcpProxy
              stat_prefix: ingress_tcp
              cluster: gateway_teamviewer
              access_log:
              - name: envoy.access_loggers.file
                typed_config:
                  "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.access_loggers.file.v3.FileAccessLog
                  path: /dev/stdout
              - name: envoy.access_loggers.file
                typed_config:
                  "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.access_loggers.file.v3.FileAccessLog
                  path: /var/log/envoy_tcpaccessLog.log            
      clusters:
      - name: AuthServer
        connect_timeout: 0.25s
        type: LOGICAL_DNS
        # Comment out the following line to test on v6 networks
        dns_lookup_family: V4_ONLY
        lb_policy: ROUND_ROBIN
        load_assignment:
          cluster_name: AuthServer
          endpoints:
          - lb_endpoints:
            - endpoint:
                address:
                  socket_address:
                    address: ${WindowsHostName}
                    port_value: 10002
        transport_socket:
          name: envoy.transport_sockets.tls
          typed_config:
            "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.transport_sockets.tls.v3.UpstreamTlsContext
      - name: SmartServer
        connect_timeout: 0.25s
        type: LOGICAL_DNS
        dns_lookup_family: V4_ONLY
        lb_policy: ROUND_ROBIN
        load_assignment:
          cluster_name: SmartServer
          endpoints:
          - lb_endpoints:
            - endpoint:
                address:
                  socket_address:
                    address: smartguide
                    port_value: 8080
      - name: dlServer
        connect_timeout: 0.25s
        type: LOGICAL_DNS
        # Comment out the following line to test on v6 networks
        dns_lookup_family: V4_ONLY
        lb_policy: ROUND_ROBIN
        load_assignment:
          cluster_name: dlServer
          endpoints:
          - lb_endpoints:
            - endpoint:
                address:
                  socket_address:
                    address: ${WindowsHostName}
                    port_value: 10100
      - name: SmartService
        connect_timeout: 0.25s
        type: LOGICAL_DNS
        # Comment out the following line to test on v6 networks
        dns_lookup_family: V4_ONLY
        lb_policy: ROUND_ROBIN
        load_assignment:
          cluster_name: SmartService
          endpoints:
          - lb_endpoints:
            - endpoint:
                address:
                  socket_address:
                    address: ${WindowsHostName}
                    port_value: 10101
      - name: MetaDataServer
        connect_timeout: 0.25s
        type: LOGICAL_DNS
        # Comment out the following line to test on v6 networks
        dns_lookup_family: V4_ONLY
        lb_policy: ROUND_ROBIN
        load_assignment:
          cluster_name: MetaDataServer
          endpoints:
          - lb_endpoints:
            - endpoint:
                address:
                  socket_address:
                    address: ${WindowsHostName}
                    port_value: 10200
      - name: gRPCServer
        connect_timeout: 0.25s
        type: strict_dns
        # Comment out the following line to test on v6 networks
        dns_lookup_family: V4_ONLY
        lb_policy: ROUND_ROBIN
        http2_protocol_options: {}
        load_assignment:
          cluster_name: gRPCServer
          endpoints:
          - lb_endpoints:
            - endpoint:
                address:
                  socket_address:
                    address: ${WindowsHostName}
                    port_value: 32915
      - name: gRPCProgressServer
        connect_timeout: 0.25s
        type: strict_dns
        # Comment out the following line to test on v6 networks
        dns_lookup_family: V4_ONLY
        lb_policy: ROUND_ROBIN
        http2_protocol_options: {}
        load_assignment:
          cluster_name: gRPCProgressServer
          endpoints:
          - lb_endpoints:
            - endpoint:
                address:
                  socket_address:
                    address: ${ReaderHostName}
                    port_value: 44151
      - name: gateway_cluster
        connect_timeout: 0.25s
        type: LOGICAL_DNS
        lb_policy: ROUND_ROBIN
        load_assignment:
          cluster_name: gateway_cluster
          endpoints:
          - lb_endpoints:
            - endpoint:
                address:
                  socket_address:
                    address: ${GatewayHostName}
                    port_value: 32914
      - name: gateway_teamviewer
        connect_timeout: 0.25s
        type: LOGICAL_DNS
        lb_policy: ROUND_ROBIN
        load_assignment:
          cluster_name: gateway_teamviewer
          endpoints:
          - lb_endpoints:
            - endpoint:
                address:
                  socket_address:
                    address: ${GatewayHostName}
                    port_value: 11080
```

Comment: can you share your envoy config file and the version of envoy you're using?  It will help look into this

Comment: @justincely :thank you and  Yeah sure, I have attached the yaml in the question and the Envoy version I'm using is v1.15.0. Thank You. 

Problem of delay start here I guess is happening because of unresolved placeholder here (i.e. ${ReaderHostName}). If I provide proper IP/hostname here then no issues. My worry is while installing if server is not up then there will be unnecessary delay in envoy initialization which I want to avoid.

Comment: @justincely Did you get a chance to look into this? any lead please?

Comment: sorry, no, i forgot to check into this.  I'll look monday morning.

Comment: sorry, I can't reproduce this at all.  I took your exact config, ran it with envoy 1.15 and it starts up within milliseconds for me.  Whether I've got the host env vars specified or not.

Comment: I'd suggest setting the `runtime` component log level to something lower and see if the logs help.  [docs](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/start/quick-start/run-envoy#debugging-envoy) give examples on this; just add this to the runtime command `--component-log-level runtime:debug` and lets see if that gives any insight.

Comment: LMK if you get a chance to run it with the extra logging and I can try to assist more

Comment: Sorry forgot to update here, Installing dnsname plugin solved this issue though we implemented that for other purpose.
https://github.com/containers/dnsname